# Print output not showing the correct format

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython

I have written the python code as below:

```
magicNumber = 25

for n in range(100):
    if n is magicNumber:
        print(n, " is the magic number")
        break
    else:
        print(n)
```

The last line of output is showing in the format as below:

```
(25, ' is the magic number')
```

Please let me know what can i do to have the `last line` of the `output` as:

```
25 is the magic number
```

Comment: You're using python 2 not 3

Comment: if you r using python 2 remove brackets().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's many ways you can accomplish this, since you're using python 2, there isn't a default print function. So you will have to import it, one way will be to add this on the top of your code.

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Other ways include using string formatting such as:

```
print "%s is the magic number" % n
```

And

```
print "{0} is the magic number".format(n)
```

Or you can just easily remove the brackets and it will all be the same.

```
print n, "is the magic number"
```

Answer (score 1):

You're running the code in python 2. That explains the braces being printed. Run in python 3 it'll work as you expect. Or if you still prefer python 2,then just remove the braces and put

```
print n,' is the magicnumber'
```

Answer (score 1):

for python 2.x  - print acts as a command
just remove the brackets and it will work as expected.

`print n, " is the magic number"`

for python 3.x - print acts as a function; so below is fine.

`print(n, " is the magic number")`

There are some other methods also as suggested by the user abccd.